# Order the numbers of each row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula `=SMALL(RIGHT($A3:$f3,1),{1,2,3,4,5,6})` and it works fine to extract one digit from the data. 
Now I have a different set of data but I couldn't make it work with these data. 
The data I have is like this:

```
L18 L2  R3  R19 R21 R22
L23 L12 L15 L17 L2  R13
L11 L17 L2  R2  R9  R24
L22 L5  L9  R9  R24 R27
```

With the function, I should be able to get these results:

```
2   3   18  19  21  22
2   12  13  15  17  23
2   2   9   11  17  24
5   9   9   22  24  27
```

So they have one letter and 1 or 2 digit numbers at the end. For each row, I would like to extract the digits and arrange them from smallest to largest. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=SMALL(--MID($A1:$F1,2,255),{1,2,3,4,5,6})
```

[image]

Given your initial formula I presume you know that this is an array formula and needs to be entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: @CallumDA can explain what that `--` means

Comment: @PraveenRKaruppannan It's the same as your `VALUE`. It converts something to a numeric value from a string/boolean

Answer (score 1):

you can do this in two Phase

As given below

`=VALUE(MID(A2,LEN(LEFT(A2,1))+1,LEN(A2)-1))`

`=SMALL($A8:$F8,1)`

[image]

Comment: @user761065 what you are tying to do with small function